# Delete default package in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I Have DataLayer and logicLayer as packages in my project. I want to delete the default package since I do not need it. But When I delete I got the following error.

> Error: Could not find or load main class

How can I slove this problem?

Comment: Are you sure that there wasn't any class inside the default package? Also make sure that you have the proper run configurations setup for the project

Comment: Seems You deleted class which contain your main method with the package.

Answer (score 8):

Move your main class from the default package to any other package and then a simple refresh would solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the default packeg is contains a class which is empty but cause problem.As soon as I delete that class the package is delete automatically.

Answer (score 0):

just create a package and it will solve the problem. Then relauch your application.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).